# Programmatically applying Hue and Saturation to Image in PictureBox C#

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone-8

How can we change the Hue and Saturation of an Image inside a PictureBox?

Below is a screenshot of an app I wrote for Windows Phone. The first image shows a blue note icon, the second, shows an orange-red note icon.

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is change the hue/saturation of certain UI elements (toolbar icons (with images)) when hovered-over. Instead of loading all these images and having 2-3 different color variations for each image. I would prefer to just have 1 image and just programmatically change the hue and saturation accordingly when the image is hovered over:

Original image:

[image]

**Altered** image (desired effect when changing hue/saturnation programmatically):

[image]

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14364716/1324033 (you change the hue of the image not the picturebox)

Comment: Thanks @Sayse, I just saw that but for some reason didn't think it was related. I'll reread it and see what I can do. :-)

Comment: No worries, I saw a few different links to "change hue c#"

Comment: Ah crud, it doesn't work. I used it, and changed the values accordingly. I change the Hue value in SetPixel to y == 137 and also if(y >= 130 && y <= 139) but it doesn't do anything. And I know for sure the color hue of the image is 137.